# How to insert XML data into SQL Server table using XmlTextReader in C# console app?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, ado.net

I have a 4GB XML file. Some of its values I have to insert into a table in the database. I wrote a stored procedure and the code in the c# console but it is not inserting the data into the database. Also, it is not throwing any error. Below is the code I have written and also the stored procedure.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string first_name=" ";
    string middle_name = "";
    string surname = "";
    string gender = "";
    string occ_title = "";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DawJoneList;Data Source=ARBENITA";

        conn.Open();

        using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("D:\\test.xml"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("spInsertimiListes", conn); 

                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    first_name = " ";
                    middle_name = " ";
                    surname = " ";
                    gender = " ";
                    occ_title =  " ";

                    foreach (var item in reader.Name)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == "FirstName")
                        {
                            first_name = reader.ReadString();
                        }
                        else if (reader.Name == "MiddleName")
                        {
                            middle_name = reader.ReadString();
                        }
                        else if (reader.Name == "Surname")
                        {
                            surname = reader.ReadString();
                        }
                        else if (reader.Name == "Gender")
                        {
                            gender = reader.ReadString();
                        }
                        else if (reader.Name == "OccTitle")
                        {
                            occ_title = reader.ReadString();
                        }
                    }
                }

                insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", first_name);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("MiddleName", middle_name);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Surname", surname);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Gender", gender);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("OccTitle", occ_title); 

                if (!((first_name == " " & surname == " " & middle_name == " " & gender == " " & occ_title == " ")))
                {
                    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

The stored procedure is like below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertimiListes]   
    @FirstName NCHAR(500),   
    @MiddleName NCHAR(500),
    @Surname NCHAR(500),
    @Gender NCHAR(100),
    @OccTitle NVARCHAR(MAX)  
AS   
    INSERT INTO Person_details (FirstName, MiddleName, Surname, Gender, OccTitle)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @MiddleName, @Surname, @Gender, @OccTitle)
```

The XML I am using for testing is :

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<Person>
<Name_details>
    <FirstName>
        Nancy    
    </FirstName>
    <MiddleName>
        Ndov
    </MiddleName>
        <Surname>
        Davolio
        </Surname>
        <Gender>
        Female
        </Gender>
        <OccTitle>
        Author
        </OccTitle>
</Name_details>
<Name_details>
    <FirstName>
        Janet    
    </FirstName>
    <MiddleName>
        Leverling
    </MiddleName>
        <Surname>
        Loving
        </Surname>
        <Gender>
        Female
        </Gender>
        <OccTitle>
        Doctor
        </OccTitle>
</Name_details>
<Name_details>
    <FirstName>
        Margaret    
    </FirstName>
    <MiddleName>
        Jaanna
    </MiddleName>
        <Surname>
        Peacock
        </Surname>
        <Gender>
        Male
        </Gender>
        <OccTitle>
        Programer
        </OccTitle>
    </Name_details>
</Person>
```

Why is this code not inserting the XML data into the databae? Any help, please!

Comment: did you debug the code? does your execution reaching to breakpoint at `insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`?

Comment: No it is not reaching there,it stays in the foreach loop

Comment: share the sample xml data in your question

Comment: Problem for me here: if (!((first_name == " " & surname == " " & middle_name == " " & gender == " " & occ_title == " ")))

Comment: this '&' should be '&&'

Comment: The problem is that it can not move to the next node to read. It stays forever in the loop to the same node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("D:\\test.xml"))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("spInsertimiListes", conn);

                    if (reader.IsStartElement("Name_details"))
                    {
                        first_name = " ";
                        middle_name = " ";
                        surname = " ";
                        gender = " ";
                        occ_title = " ";

                        while(reader.Read() && reader.IsStartElement())
                        {
                            switch(reader.Name)
                            {
                                case "FirstName":
                                    first_name = reader.ReadString();
                                    break;
                                case "MiddleName":
                                    middle_name = reader.ReadString();
                                    break;
                                case "Surname":
                                    surname = reader.ReadString();
                                    break;
                                case "Gender":
                                    gender = reader.ReadString();
                                    break;
                                case "OccTitle":
                                    occ_title = reader.ReadString();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    throw new InvalidExpressionException("Unexpected tag");
                            }
                            reader.ReadEndElement();
                        }
                    }

                    insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", first_name);
                    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("MiddleName", middle_name);
                    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Surname", surname);
                    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Gender", gender);
                    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("OccTitle", occ_title);

                    if (!((first_name == " " && surname == " " && middle_name == " " && gender == " " && occ_title == " ")))
                    {
                        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `reader.read()` will read only the root node and there is only one node, so it won't move to next node. You should be navigating to child nodes by using `ReadToDescendant` method. The below code might work for you. Check my comments in the code.

```
          using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("D:\\test.xml"))
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("Person"); // it will read the first node
                    if (reader.ReadToDescendant("Name_details")) // it will read the first descendent of Person
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("spInsertimiListes", conn);

                            if (reader.IsStartElement())
                            {
                                first_name = " ";
                                middle_name = " ";
                                surname = " ";
                                gender = " ";
                                occ_title = " ";

                                foreach (var item in reader.Name)
                                {
                                    if (reader.Name == "FirstName")
                                    {
                                        first_name = reader.ReadString();
                                    }
                                    else if (reader.Name == "MiddleName")
                                    {
                                        middle_name = reader.ReadString();
                                    }
                                    else if (reader.Name == "Surname")
                                    {
                                        surname = reader.ReadString();
                                    }
                                    else if (reader.Name == "Gender")
                                    {
                                        gender = reader.ReadString();
                                    }
                                    else if (reader.Name == "OccTitle")
                                    {
                                        occ_title = reader.ReadString();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", first_name);
                            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("MiddleName", middle_name);
                            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Surname", surname);
                            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Gender", gender);
                            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("OccTitle", occ_title);

                            if (!((first_name == " " & surname == " " & middle_name == " " & gender == " " & occ_title == " ")))
                            {
                                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("Name_details")); // it will read next descendent of person
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks, Vinit but it is still staying at Name_details element in the loop and is not inserting data